# Google+ sign in verification issue

Tags: javascript, php, google-plus

Hello I am trying to implement Google+ sign in on my website, I have gotten everything working except for the part where the php will check the users google ID and email to see if they have an account or i need to create one for them.

The problem I am having is how can I verify that what the php recieves from the javascript on the client is in fact valid? I mean it seems someone could easily modify the script to send any google users ID and Email and then sign in as anyone. How do I prevent this?

I have been following this google guide so far https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button

They don't say anything about how to verify on the backend the user thats signed in is really the real user or not, am I using the wrong one for my purpose, I don't need any offline access to their account info, only when they are logged into the site and active.

Comment: To sign in to google+ you need an E-mail address and the Password. So anyone can know a client E-mail address, because they can give it out to anyone. However, to log in to his/her account, you also need the "Password".

Comment: @Juniar The entire point of Google+ Sign-In is so you don't have to ask users for passwords. Sites should **never** ask for Google passwords.

Comment: @abraham Without the password then I guess anybody with a valid E-mail address can sign in regardless of the E-mail: Ownership. So privacy is not important.

Comment: Have a look at OAuth, it's a secure method for accessing private content without passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step 5 from you link there is an authorization object of success results. This contains an `access_token`. This access_token is a secret that identifies and grants access based on the requested permissions to the specific users who was authorized. Pass this access_token to your backend via XHR or other method and use it to make an authenticated request to [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) with a userId set to `me`. This will tell you who the user is and if you request the `email` scope their verified email address.

Comment: Do I have to pass the access_token back using HTTPS or can I just use HTTP. I've tried cors but it just isnt working. The server has no SSL certificate either.

Comment: You really should use SSL for your entire site. Otherwise any person on the same wifi access to networking equipment between their browser and your server can hijack their access_token.